# Why can't I check ActiveRecord validations in the console?

Tags: ruby, validation, activerecord, console

I'm learning RoR at the moment, and I think I must be misunderstanding something.

I have an ActiveRecord class call User, with simple validations on :name and :email such as presence: true, length: { maximum: 15 }, etc. I thought I'd check the validations in the console. I go into rails console (development env), and create a new instance with a name that is too long, such as
user_instance = User.new (name:"aaaaabbbbbcccccddddd", email:"").

The validation doesn't throw up any errors. When I try user_instance.save, the record won't write to the DB, so it's obviously working fine at that stage. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13):

When you want to get an exception raised on record saving, use [`save!`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000396) instead of [`save`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000395) (same with `update`/`update!`, `create/create!`).

With `save` you won't have an exception raised if there are validation errors, it will just return `false`. You can also check if there are errors on an instance with `user_instance.valid?` and get the errors with `user_instance.errors`.

See [When Does Validation Happen?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#when-does-validation-happen).

Comment: Thanks Florent2, very helpful

Comment: Super helpful - been transitioning to rails for over a year and somehow this had eluded me

Comment: Perhaps this is available in a newer version of `Rails`, I use `user_instances.errors.full_messages`. You are shown the errors in a human readable format.

Answer (score 5):

the validation won't throw errors if you try to set invalid data  on your model, however the save will fail.

if you wanna check out if the validation is working correctly, just check **user.valid?** and it should return false

after calling **valid?**, you can check **user.errors** for the specific errors set on your model.

Comment: Thanks, Bassam, that makes sense to me now, and I can see user_instance.valid? is returning a hash @messages with the validation results.